# How can I split a module into multiple files, without breaking a backwards compatibly?

Tags: python, module

Let's say I have a `model.py` file that looks like this:

```
class Foo():
  ..

class Bar():
  ..
```

From other modules I'm importing the `model` and then using `model.Foo()` 
whenever I want to refer to them.

```
import model

foo = model.Foo()
```

As this file is growing bigger I would like to split each class
into multiple files, but without breaking the backwards compatibility if
possible.

My idea was to break it like this:

```
model
├── __init__.py
├── foo.py
└── bar.py
```

but by doing that I will have to refer to them as `model.foo.Foo()`.

So my question is: is it possible to split it in multiple files somehow but still referring to them as `model.Foo()`?

I should also be able to extend or use `Foo` inside `Bar`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Sure you can, just import the classes in the `__init__.py`:

```
# in __init__.py
from model.foo import Foo
from model.bar import Bar
```

And then when you wish to use them you can:

```
>>> import model
>>> model.Bar()
<model.bar.Bar object at 0x31306d0>
```

or

```
>>> from model import Foo
>>> Foo()
<model.foo.Foo object at 0x31307d0>
```

Comment: Actually in a brand new project it worked, but how could I import `Foo` in the `bar.py`?

Comment: Just `import model` in `bar.py`. Or `from model import Foo`. Works the same way.

Comment: The problem was somewhere else in the original project but one evil try/catch was preventing me to connect the dots! One more question, is it possible somehow to import all of them without explicitly doing that one by one?

Comment: I can't really test it now but `from model import *` might do the trick.

Comment: @Lipis yeah, both the `from model import *` and `import model` will work. Importing the model allows you to say `model.Foo()`.

Comment: @msvalkon What I meant is to be able to add a new model file into that module and without editing the `__init__.py` file make it work like `model.NewEntity`, but I guess that is not very doable

Comment: @Lipis ah yes. You'll have to add each new model file separately to the `__init__.py`.

Comment: Yes.. doing that already.. https://github.com/gae-init/gae-init/tree/master/main/model thanks :)