# Can a Python module be multiple files?

Tags: python, module, package

For years, I've known that the very definition of a Python module is as a separate file. In fact, even the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) states that "a module is a file containing Python definitions and statements". Yet, this [online tutorial](https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_py.html) from people who seem pretty knowledgeable states that "a module usually corresponds to a single file". Where does the "usually" come from? Can a Python module consist of multiple files?

Comment: A module can be an `__init__.py` file that imports (and makes available for importing) functions and classes from an entire subtree of files.  So it's probably correct in one sense to say that the "module" is just that one file, but in a more useful sense you'd say that the "module" is the entire subtree.

Comment: By that logic - imports - almost any python module is multifile.  Unless the imports are from the subtree, which has no real discernible difference to code using the module.  `__module__` also maps to one file.  The usefulness of expanding the definition of modules that way seems… limited, and risks confusion.  Let imports be imports ans modules be modules.

Comment: The *online tutorial* specifically refers to *packages*. And a package is precisely something that consists on several files (or modules) but that can be imported in one single operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

Don't read too much into the phrasing of one short throwaway sentence, in a much larger blog post that concerns packaging and packages, both of which *are* by nature multi-file.

##### Imports do not make modules multifile

By the logic that modules are multifile because of imports... almost any python module is multifile. Unless the imports are from the subtree, which has no real discernible difference to code using the module.  That notion of subtree imports, btw, *is* relevant... to Python packages.

`__module__`, the attribute found on classes and functions, also maps to one file, as determined by import path.

**The usefulness of expanding the definition of modules that way seems… limited, and risks confusion. Let imports be imports ans modules be modules (i.e. files).**

But that's like, my personal opinion.

##### Let's go all language lawyer on it

And refer to the Python tutorial.  I figure they will be talking about modules at some point and will be much more careful in their wording than a blog post which was primarily concerned about another subject.

[6. Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

> To support this, Python has a way to put definitions in a file and use them in a script or in an interactive instance of the interpreter. **Such a file is called a module**; definitions from a module can be imported into other modules or into the main module (the collection of variables that you have access to in a script executed at the top level and in calculator mode).
>
> **A module is a file** containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended. Within a module, the module’s name (as a string) is available as the value of the global variable **name**.

p.s. OK, what about calling it a *file*, instead of a *module*, then?

That supposes that you store Python code in a file system.  But you could have an exotic environment that stores it in a database instead (or embeds it in a larger C/Rust executable?).  So, *module*, seems better understood as a "contiguous chunk of Python code".  Usually that's a file, but having a separate term allows for flexibility, without changing anything to the core concepts.

Comment: This question is a top result, in a search about this python topic.  And it seems to be wrong, saying "not really". You can break a module into multiple files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100558/how-can-i-split-a-module-into-multiple-files-without-breaking-a-backwards-compa

Comment: "It’s important to keep in mind that all packages are modules" – Martijn Pieters. That would mean that if we are venturing into the world of "packages" well it's also still a module.  Which has been split into multiple files, such as the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure.
If you create a folder named `mylib` in your PATH or in the same directory as your script, it allows you to use `import mylib`.
Make sure to put `__init__.py` in the folder and in that imoprt everything from other files because the variables, functions, etc. import just from the `__init__.py`.

For example:

```
project -+- lib -+- __init__.py
         |       +- bar.py
         |       +- bar2.py
         |
         +- foo.py
```

__init__.py :

```
from bar import test, random
from bar2 import sample
```

foo.py :

```
import lib

print(test)
sample()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, a python module can include more than one file. Basically what you would do is get a file for the main code of the module you are writing, and in that main file include some other tools you can use.

For example, you can have the file my_splitter_module.py, in which you have... say a function that gets a list of integers and split it in half creating two lists. Now say you wanna multiply all the numbers that are in the first half between each other ([1, 2, 3] -> 1 * 2 * 3), but with the other half sum them ([1, 2, 3] -> 1 + 2 + 3). Now say you don't want to make the code messy and so you decide to make another two functions, one that gets a list and multiply its items, and another that sum them.

Of course, you could make the two functions in the same my_splitter_module.py file, but in other situations when you have big files with big classes etc, you would like to make a file like multiply_list.py and sum_list.py, and then importing them to the my_splitter_module.py

At the end, you would import my_splitter_module.py to your main.py file, and while doing this, you would also be importing multiply_list.py and sum_list.py files.